# Getting Hard Disk Speed using C#

Tags: c#

It is possible to get Hard Disk Information using C#?

```
Like spin rate in RPM
Model Number 
Company Name
Data Transfer Rate
Seek Time
```

most importantly spin rate.

I have tried with

```
ManagementClass driveClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_DiskDrive");
```

properties but it's not giving spin rate.

Please help me?

- Dattatrya Moin

Comment: It probably depends upon the operating system. On Linux you might read some files under /proc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382547/how-can-i-find-hard-disk-speed

Comment: Yes, with Mono, you get C# on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and try this:

```cs
ArrayList hddCollection = new ArrayList();
try
{
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");
    foreach (ManagementObject wmiObj in searcher.Get)
    {
        HardDrive hdd = new HardDrive();
        hdd.model = wmiObj("Model").ToString;
        hdd.type = wmiObj("InterfaceType").ToString;
        hddCollection.Add(hdd);
        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit For
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check this : [Reading ATAPI SMART Data from Drives using .NET; Temperature Anyone?](http://vasters.com/clemensv/2011/04/11/Reading+ATAPI+SMART+Data+From+Drives+Using+NET+Temperature+Anyone.aspx)

```
using System.Management;

public string GetHDDSerial()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

    foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
    {
        // get the hardware serial no.
        if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] != null)
            return wmi_HD["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```